# How to detect mouse clicks in a live feed using opencv

Tags: c++, callback, opencv3.0

I am new to Opencv, i am debugging a simple program that would count the number and position of mouse click using setMouseCallback function on a live stream from a video camera, but as soon as the program starts, it gets struck and the position and number of mouse clicks are updated because of the movement of mouse instead of clicks. I am including my program below, i would be grateful if anybody points the mistake and as well as give me a solution for the above mentioned program.

```
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define window "LiveFeed"
Mat frame;

void cbmouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*userdata)
{
    static int count = 0;
    char text[] = "count999";
    if (event = EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            circle(frame, Point(x, y), 4, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            count++;
            sprintf(text, "count%d", count);
            putText(frame, text, Point(x + 5, y + 2), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2);
            imshow(window, frame);
            if (waitKey(33) == 27)
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    VideoCapture video(0);
    namedWindow(window);
    while (1)
    {
        video >> frame;
        imshow(window, frame);
        setMouseCallback(window, cbmouse, NULL);
        if (waitKey(33) == 27)
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need only correction of `if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)`

but i did some improvements. Please try the code below.(i am not sure, do you want to freeze the live feed when you clicked first ?)

```
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define window "LiveFeed"
Mat frame;

vector<Point> pts;

void drawClickedPoints( Mat img )
{

    for(size_t i = 0; i < pts.size(); i++)
    {
        circle(img, pts[i], 4, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        putText(frame, format("count%d", i), Point(pts[i].x + 5, pts[i].y + 2), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2);
    }

}
void cbmouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*userdata)
{
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        pts.push_back(Point(x,y));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    VideoCapture video(0);
    namedWindow(window);
    setMouseCallback(window, cbmouse, NULL);
    while (1)
    {
        video >> frame;
        drawClickedPoints(frame);
        imshow(window, frame);
        if (waitKey(33) == 27)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya, i thought of editing it, and thanks for the answer it works flawlessly.